# How to select query's result to JSON in Rust and Nickel?

Tags: rust, nickel

I use nickel.rs:

```
router.get("/api/movies", middleware! { |request, response|
    let mut test_movies =
    r#"[
        { "title": "Ironman"},
        { "title": "The Walk"},
        { "title": "Paddington"}
    ]
    "#;
    let json = Json::from_str(test_movies);
    format!("{}", json.unwrap())
});
```

I wanted to create JSON format. The code for connecting to PostgreSQL and converting to JSON definition is below:

```
extern crate rustc_serialize;
use rustc_serialize::json::{Json, Parser};

#[derive(RustcDecodable, RustcEncodable)]
struct Movie {
    title: String,
}
```

And I tried to select query and create JSON

```
router.get("/api/movies", middleware! { |request, response|
    let conn = Connection::connect("postgres://postgres@localhost", SslMode::None).unwrap();
    let stmt = match conn.prepare("select title from movie") {
        Ok(stmt) => stmt,
        Err(e) => {
            return response.send(format!("Preparing query failed: {}", e));
        }
    };
    let res = match stmt.execute(&[]) {
        Ok(v) => println!("Selecting movie was Success."),
        Err(e) => println!("Selecting movie failed. => {:?}", e)
    };

    // ???
    // let movies = Json::from_obj(res);
    // let movies = request.json_as::<&[Movie]>().unwrap();
    // let movies = request.json_as::Vec<Movie>().unwrap();
    format!("{}", movies)
});
```

however, I have no idea how to convert the result to JSON.

```
let conn = conn.clone();
```

makes the errors.

```
error: no method named `clone` found for type `postgres::Connection` in the current scope
```

I added

```
use nickel::status::StatusCode;

//use rustc_serialize::json::{Json, Parser};
use rustc_serialize::{json};

json::encode(&movies).unwrap();
```

was work. but null returned...

**Finally**

I changed `execute` to `query` and also use `Vec<Movie>`.

```
let mut v: Vec<Movie> = vec![];
let movies = &conn.query("select title from movie", &[]).unwrap();
for row in movies {
    let movie = Movie {
        title: row.get(0),
    };

    v.push(movie);
}

let json_obj = json::encode(&v).unwrap();
response.set(MediaType::Json);
response.set(StatusCode::Ok);
return response.send(json_obj);
```

I also defined `struct` Moview like model

```
struct Movie {
    // id: i32,
    title: String,
}
```

hmm.. troublesome a lot.

however, I can't `conn.clone()` yet.

Comment: Have you tried `json::encode(&movies).unwrap()`?

Comment: I mistook.

so I changed code

    use rustc_serialize::{json};

and it worked. but null

Comment: Please have a look at my updated answer to solve the cloning problem.

Comment: It similar problem. same warning. but I can't fix
https://github.com/nickel-org/nickel.rs/issues/255

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
    let json = json::encode(&res).unwrap();
    response.set(MediaType::Json);
    response.set(StatusCode::Ok);
    return response.send(json);
```

Also, it's not efficient to create a new connection for each request. You can create one connection in the main() function and then clone it inside each request closure.

```
fn main(){

    let mut server = Nickel::new();
    let mut router = Nickel::router();

    let conn = Connection::connect("postgres://postgres@localhost", SslMode::None).unwrap();
    let shared_connection = Arc::new(conn);


    {
        let conn = shared_connection.clone();
        router.get("/api/movies", middleware! ( |request, mut response|{

            let mut v: Vec<Movie> = vec![];
            let movies = &conn.query("select title", &[]).unwrap();
            for row in movies {
                let movie = Movie {
                    title: row.get(0),
                };

                v.push(movie);
            }

            let json_obj = json::encode(&v).unwrap();
            res.set(MediaType::Json);
            res.set(StatusCode::Ok);
            return res.send(json_obj);

        }));
    }

    {
        let conn = shared_connection.clone();
        router.post("/api/movies",middleware!(|request, mut response|{

            //...

        }));
    }

    server.utilize(router);
    server.listen("127.0.0.1:6767");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for replying.
Yes. I think it is bad to make new connection for each request.
I tried let conn = conn.clone();

   error: no method named `clone` found for type `postgres::Connection` in the current scope

error happned.
I added

     use nickel::status::StatusCode;

And, I fix 
    use rustc_serialize::json::{Json, Parser};

to

   use rustc_serialize::{json};

I modify res to movies. Your code was no error. 

But, null was return. I certainly interted data. Why it happned?

Comment: Selecting movie was Success.

log shows. so, I guess SQL is correct.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the inconsistencies in my answer. I'll update it to match your original code. Are you using the library `sfackler/rust-postgres`? If so, its documentation states that `execute()` returns the number of rows affected while `query()` returns an iterable object. So I suggest you try using `query()`.

Comment: yes. I wrote `postgres = "0.11"` of `[dependencies]` in `Cargo.toml`.
And, I wrote `use postgres::{Connection, SslMode};` in my `main.rs`.
So, there are a lot of libs? I also wrote `use nickel_postgres::{PostgresMiddleware, PostgresRequestExtensions};`... however it weren't used..

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to initialize Atomic Reference Counting `Arc` for the connection.You should be able to `clone()` now

Comment: <nickel macros>:22:50: 22:66 error: the trait `core::marker::Sync` is not implemented for the type `core::cell::UnsafeCell<postgres::InnerConnection>` 
happened

Comment: I added `use std::sync::{Arc};`
must I modify Connection souce code?

Comment: If the `Sync` trait hasn't been implemented for `Connection` then you can either create a new connection with each request otherwise, I think it's best to first raise an issue on the `sfackler/rust-postgres` repository. They will either guide you to their intended way of sharing a connection otherwise you can implement Sync for Connection and send a pull request.

Comment: It is my code now https://github.com/shinriyo/nickel-helloworld.git

I'm not similar to Angular js so I can't delete and update movie yet...

Comment: `let shared_connection = Arc::new(Mutex::new(conn));`

Comment: author replied my topic

Comment: no. I fix
`let shared_connection = Arc::new(Mutex::<Connection>::new(conn));`
but... not work